# Error code is 0 but Jenkins job is failure

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

I always get jenkins failure:

> Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

but when I put in batch command:  "echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%" I get 0 code.

My batch command is:

```
ELSE (
   ROBOCOPY.EXE C:\dir2\ C:\dir1\ script.bat /IS
   cd C:\dir1\
   echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%
   C:\dir1\script.bat
   echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%
   ROBOCOPY.EXE C:\dir1 C:\dir3 /E /IS /XF *.config 
   echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%
)
echo TEST
```

Command echo TEST is never shown. When I delete from batch "C:\dir1\script.bat" everything works fine and jenkins job is success.

Script bat contains only commands like:

> del .\bin\library.dll

What do you think, the problem is with script.bat? When I add in the end of this script: EXIT /B 0 , the job is also failed.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to provide us with more than the half-statement here for a definitive answer. It may be that the `)` before the `else` is missing (it **must** be on the same line as the `else` keyword).

More likely, you are victim number 48 million of the `delayed expansion` problem. See endless examples on SO.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Hence, you are seeing the value of `errorlevel` as it existed when the (presumed) `IF` was **parsed** - before execution.

Comment: Yes, I have ) before the else statement. This is ok. I change setlocal and I add 'echo Exit Code is !errorlevel!' but it doesnt show any value (only !errorlevel!). I still have problem with failure in jenkins. I really dont have any idea why it still happening. Please, help.

Comment: Have you used a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` instruction before the `if`? If you have not, then the `echo` will show `!errorlevel!` as you report.

Comment: Yes, of course. I put instruction before if:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
IF '%domain-name%' == 'xxx' (...
)ELSE (...
)